# JavaScript: How to pass arguments to a listener function that will eventually be removed

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

I am trying to call a function that has parameters on which it depends when an event is triggered. This function however must not be anonymous because the listener will be removed in the future.

I attempted to use a function expression for the wrapper, and pass a reference to `this` as a parameter in the primary function:

```
<div id="div">
  click
</div>
```

```js
function main() {
  let foo = "foo";
  let bar = "bar";
  let wrapFunction = function(event) {
    goodFunction(event, foo, bar, this);
  }
  document.getElementById("div").addEventListener("click", wrapFunction);
}
function goodFunction(e, foo, bar, wrapFunction) {
  alert(foo);
  alert(bar);
  document.getElementById("div").removeEventListener("click", wrapFunction);
}
main();
```

Everything works fine except for the `document.getElementById("div").removeEventListener("click", wrapFunction);` line. This is the part I cannot figure out, and help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than pass `this` to the `goodFunction(event, foo, bar, this)` call inside of `wrapFunction`, you could just pass `wrapFunction` itself seeing that it is defined by the time the handler is called:

```js
function main() {
  let foo = "foo";
  let bar = "bar";
  let wrapFunction = function(event) {

    /* wrapFunction is defined so pass it directly to goodFunction */
    goodFunction(event, foo, bar, wrapFunction);
  }
  document.getElementById("div").addEventListener("click", wrapFunction);
}

function goodFunction(e, foo, bar, wrapFunction) {
  alert(foo);
  alert(bar);
  document.getElementById("div").removeEventListener("click", wrapFunction);
}
main();
```

```html
<div id="div">Click me</div>
```